# Variable argument in SQL functions

Tags: sql, function, parameters

I wrote this code in SQL :

```
create function addition
    (@a decimal, @b decimal)
returns decimal as
begin
    declare @return decimal

    set @return = @a + @b

    return @return
end
```

This function will only accept two parameters.

I want to create a function which accepts multiple arguments / parameters, like `concat()` handles multiple parameters.

Is there is a way to achieve it?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: For SQL Server, you would probably want to use a [table-valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15). But as jarlh said, the answer will depend on which DBMS you're using, and potentially on the specific version as well.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't found wether it's possible or not to create a UDF in Sql Server that would accept any number of parameters. Like as `CONCAT` does.  *(maybe a CLR function???)*

But here are examples of 2 alternatives

**A) Create a table type. And use that in the UDF**

> ```
> CREATE TYPE dbo.[NumsType] AS TABLE(
>     [n] [int] NOT NULL
> );
> ```

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION udf_sumNums (@nums dbo.NumsType readonly) 
> RETURNS INT AS
> BEGIN
>     DECLARE @n INT;
>     SELECT @n = sum(n) FROM @nums;
>     RETURN @n;
> END;
> GO
> ```

> ```
> declare @mynums as dbo.NumsType;
>
> insert into @mynums values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
>
> select dbo.udf_sumNums(@mynums) as sums
> ```
>
> ```
> | sums |
> | ---: |
> |   15 |
> ```

**B) Feed a character separated string to the UDF. Then split the string.**

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION udf_sumNumString (@numString varchar(max)) 
> RETURNS INT AS
> BEGIN
>     DECLARE @result INT;
>     
>     SELECT @result = SUM(TRY_CAST(value as int)) 
>     FROM string_split(@numString,',');
>     
>     RETURN @result;
> END;
> ```

> ```
> select dbo.udf_sumNumString('1,2,3,4,5') as sums
> ```
>
> ```
> | sums |
> | ---: |
> |   15 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4d5318bfc553fe032ac878fa54e7d29b)*